# How to sum two columns with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I would like to do :

```
SELECT * FROM Table where (FieldA + FieldB > 90)
```

using hibernate.

I know I could get all the objects and then do the operation in Java, but there is a lot of data, and I would like to be able to do it in a simple request.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.
Solution was indeed

```
from Table as t where (t.FieldA + t.FieldB) > 90
```

Except that in order to consider null as 0 I had to use COALESCE (or ifnull)

```
from Table as t where (COALESCE(t.FieldA,0) + COALESCE(t.FieldB,0)) > 90
```

Now it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use it as an SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table where (FieldA + FieldB) > 90;
```

And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use HQL or Criteria.

If you use HQL, you have to do something like this:

```
from Table as t where (t.FieldA + t.FieldB) > 90
```

If you use Criteria, you should use Restrictions.sqlRestriction method:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Table.class);
c.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("(FieldA + FieldB) > 90"));
```

I hope this information helps you.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it can be done using HSQL:

```
select cat.weight + sum(kitten.weight) 
from Cat cat 
    join cat.kittens kitten
group by cat.id, cat.weight
```

BUT! if on of the number is null, result is null... when I would need null to be considered as 0, so this does not work

Comment: That doesn't resolve the problem in the question and there's a mistake on the `+` which should be a `,`.